# where HttpSession's setAttribute("attributename",object) Object will be stored?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, httpsession

```
class SessionStorage extends HttpServlet
{       
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        int schoolId=100;
        session.setAttribute("schoolId", schoolId);     
    }

}
```

I just want to know where the `schoolId` attribute is stored. Either it is on the web container (ex. tomcat) or in Memory (eg .RAM).
And which location i will find this attributes if it on the server?

Comment: What other memory than RAM do you think the container uses?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885525/where-is-the-httpsession-data-stored

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the HttpSession data stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885525/where-is-the-httpsession-data-stored)

Answer (score 0):

SchooldId is saved in the HttpSession (on tomcat). The HttpSession itself is stored in the server's Memory (RAM). You can only look up the value again when a new request for the same http session arrives on the server.

Comment: JVM is running on Server So In JVM different Memory area                    (like Stack,heap,method Area) used to StoreData . In Which Area the HttpSession attributes stored.  Correct me if i am wrong in above sentence.

Comment: The session is a java object, so that would be stored in the heap.

Comment: how does server know this attribute is for particular user , did it store  session Id   with attribute in heap?

Comment: Really depends on the implementation of the server but I imagine one could store it in a HashMap (which would also be contained in the heap).

Answer (score 0):

SchoolId will be stored in httpSession object. HttpSession will be created in tomcat or any other app/web server